# Go scanner - correctness for whitespace?

Tags: go

The Go scanner package in `text/scanner/scanner.go` uses trick to find whitespace:

```
const GoWhitespace = 1<<'\t' | 1<<'\n' | 1<<'\r' | 1<<' '
```

And then:

```
// skip white space
for s.Whitespace&(1<<uint(ch)) != 0 {
    ch = s.next()
}
```

Since character values shift left by more than 31, can there be cases where this is not unique? I mean, when some char is the same as tab modulo 32, it will be recognized as whitespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fully answer:

Spec explicitly say that for operations on unsigned, we get high bits masked out so the low bits are really "wrap around".

The reason it works is:

1. `Scanner.Whitespace` is actually `uint64` so value of `GoWhitespace` fully fit
2. Operation `s.Whitespace&(1<<uint(ch))` on unsigned integer at runtime can have intermediate values arbitrary large and will wrap around. So if say char is "a" (96) we have `1 << 96` which overflows so modulo size of 64-bit int it's 0.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned [in the spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Arithmetic_operators), the `<<` is a shift operation:

> The shift operators shift the left operand by the shift count specified by the right operand. They implement arithmetic shifts if the left operand is a signed integer and logical shifts if it is an unsigned integer. There is no upper limit on the shift count. Shifts behave as if the left operand is shifted n times by 1 for a shift count of n. As a result, x << 1 is the same as x*2 and x >> 1 is the same as x/2 but truncated towards negative infinity.

For large values of `ch`, `1<<uint(ch)` will [cause an overflow](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Integer_overflow):

> For unsigned integer values, the operations +, -, *, and << are computed modulo 2<sup>n</sup>, where n is the bit width of the unsigned integer's type. Loosely speaking, these unsigned integer operations discard high bits upon overflow, and programs may rely on ``wrap around''.
>
> For signed integers, the operations +, -, *, and << may legally overflow and the resulting value exists and is deterministically defined by the signed integer representation, the operation, and its operands. No exception is raised as a result of overflow. A compiler may not optimize code under the assumption that overflow does not occur. For instance, it may not assume that x < x + 1 is always true.

So implementing `<<` with a bitwise rotation operator (what you seem to be describing) would violate the spec.  `1<<uint(ch)` will evaluate to zero for values of `ch` larger than the size of the `int` type, so won't cause any false positives.

Comment: The first paragraph in the second quote says it wraps around module `2n`. Or does this not apply because `1` is signed, rather than unsigned? Even if it evaluates to zero, this means shift by space (ascii 32) is zero, which would be true for all chars > 32 as well?