# Go integer overflow settings in commandline and playground

Tags: go

This program runs fine one my machine (go1.2.1 linux/amd64):

```
package main

import "fmt"

const bigint = 1<<62

func main() {
    fmt.Println(bigint)
}
```

But with the go playground, it gives overflow error - http://play.golang.org/p/lAUwLwOIVR

It seem that my build is configured with 64 bits for integer constans, playground configured with 32 bits.

But [spec say](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Integer_overflow) that implementation must give at least 256 bits of precision for constants?

Also see code in [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22438387/720999) -- the scanner standard package has code:

```
const GoWhitespace = 1<<'\t' | 1<<'\n' | 1<<'\r' | 1<<' '
```

Since space is 32, this don't work on 32-bit playground at all.

How can this be?

Comment: When you pass the constant to Println, it is converted into an int as per spec. Try using uint64(bigint) to get the full 64 bits of precision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Constants in general

Constants itself are not limited in precision but when used in code they are converted to a suitable type. 
From the [spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants):

> **A constant may be given a type explicitly by a constant declaration or conversion, or implicitly when used in a variable declaration or an assignment or as an operand in an expression.** It is an error if the constant value cannot be represented as a value of the respective type. For instance, 3.0 can be given any integer or any floating-point type, while 2147483648.0 (equal to 1<<31) can be given the types float32, float64, or uint32 but not int32 or string.

So if you have

```
const a = 1 << 33
fmt.Println(a)
```

you will [get an overflow error](http://play.golang.org/p/b1eRjLeRyG) as the default type for integer constants `int` can't hold the value `1 << 33` on [32 bit environments](http://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#int). If you convert the constant to `int64` everything's fine on all platforms:

```
const a = 1 << 33
fmt.Println(int64(a))
```

#### Scanner

The constant `GoWhitespace` is not directly used in the scanner. 
The [Whitespace attribute](http://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/pkg/text/scanner/scanner.go?name=go1.2#165) used in the `Scanner` type is of type `uint64` and [`GoWhitespace` is assigned to it](http://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/pkg/text/scanner/scanner.go?name=go1.2#206):

```
s.Whitespace = GoWhitespace
```

This means you deal with a `uint64` value and `1 << ' '` (aka. `1 << 32`) is perfectly valid.

Example ([on play](http://play.golang.org/p/tQaqe27ko_)):

```
const w = 1<<'\t' | 1<<'\n' | 1<<'\r' | 1<<' '

c := ' '

// fmt.Println(w & (1 << uint(c))) // fails with overflow error
fmt.Println(uint64(w) & (1 << uint(c))) // works as expected
```

Comment: Ah, the conversion makes sense then. One mystery that remains is why the scanner does `1<<uint(ch)` for any input rune `ch` - since `ch` can be larger than 32. It can be `'a'` for example, which is 96 so that would do `1 << 96`.

Comment: @zlatanski As explained in the answers to your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22438781/1643939) `1 << uint(c)` will give you `0` if it overflows, which is the case for `'a'`.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by nemo, you can give a type to your constant. Just specify `int64` and it works fine :)

http://play.golang.org/p/yw2vsvMigk

```
package main

import "fmt"

const bigint int64 = 1<<62

func main() {
    fmt.Println(bigint)
}
```